# Cannot uninstall, install or repair Visual Studio 2012 & 2013

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, visual-studio-2012, windows-installer, visual-studio-2013

I have Visual Studio 2010, 2012 and 2013 installed, I want to uninstall 2013 however both 2012 & 2013 have gotten corrupted.

However, when I run the install files the installation just hangs.

- For 2012 it hangs at the first component (Microsoft 2012 IntelliTrace Front End x86)
- For 2013 it hangs a little later on .NET Framework 4.51 Multi-Target pack.

2013 will load when the icon is clicked, but crashed.

2012 is nowhere bit *is* in the Add\Remove Programs or Files window, but uninstalling gives me a dialogue that it might have already been uninstalled and would I like to remove the entry, clicking yes tells me I need admin privileges, however, I am admin.

Now I am stuck, unable to install, uninstall or anything.

I have tried running the following files:

- `en_visual_studio_professional_2012_x86_web_installer_2599144.exe`
- `en_visual_studio_ultimate_2012_x86_web_installer_2599164.exe.exe`
- `en_visual_studio_ultimate_2013_x86_web_installer_3175337.exe`

2012 Professional was there, then 2012 Ultimate and finally 2013 Ultimate.

**How to I go about investigating this?**

*Edit*

Even cancelling the setup hangs, I have to kill the tasks.

*Edit*
Both 2012 Professional and Ultimate are in `programs and Features`, however 2013 Ultimate is not (but is installed and executable, but crashes on the splash screen after loading)

[image: 2012 Pro and Ultimate present, but not 2013 Ultimate]

Comment: Your first statement does not makes sense.  If you uninstalled VS2013 of course it wouln't work.  Please clarify.

Comment: @Ramhound  It isn't uninstalled, it still fires up when I click the icon.  I want to only have 2010 and 2012 on the machine, but `en_visual_studio_ultimate_2012_x86_web_installer_2599164.exe`, `en_visual_studio_ultimate_2013_x86_web_installer_3175337` and en_visual_studio_professional_2012_x86_web_installer_2599144.exe` all hang.  I'm not even sure how 2012 professional got on there.

Comment: What?  You don't understand how VS2012 was installed.

Comment: @Ramhound I know that it was installed by running the installation exe, what else do you mean?  I've tried uninstalling 2013, this failed and left the application on the machine.  I realised Pro 2012 and Ultimate 2012 were both on the machine so I tried uninstalling these.  All of them are hanging.  I have tried repairing them, this also hangs.  Now I am lost as to how to diagnose and solve the problem.

Comment: Its not possible to have 2 versions of the same release of VS to be installed at the sametime.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, however that doesn't change the fact that I have both `Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012` and `Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012` in `Programs and Features`, neither of which I can uninstall.  Also, 2013 Ultimate IS installed, but not not showing in `Programs and `Features` and runs, but immediately crashes.

Comment: I assume Visual Studio 2010 is working fine. Is that correct? Also, have you got any restore points?

Comment: @and31415 2010 seems to be unaffected (it opens, builds etc.).  I can't see any system restore points that the 2012 or 2013 installations might have created.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Revo uninstaller. We use it a lot when a corrupted installion won't remove or repair through the usual methods. It seems to find those odd scattered bits that confuse installers.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the installer from command line and add switch for force like this:

```
installer_name.exe /u /force
```

More info on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx

Comment: Cheers, I'd already done that.  In the end, it was a reinstall of the OS.